# Disable onClick for a listview item's views during list scroll

Tags: android, listview

I am seeing a problem that happens sometimes, depending on how the user scrolls the ListView.

Basically my `ListView` item contains of some `checkboxes` and a `SwitchCompat` which all have their `OnCheckedChangeListener` set inside the `getView` of the adapter.

The problem is that, sometimes during regular scroll, the `OnCheckedChangeListener` fires and the values change, when the list should only scroll.

How should I handle this? Is there a simple way to disable any item's clicks while the list is scrolling?

Comment: I think maybe this is problem about row reuse not `OnCheckedChangeListener` fires when scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll, `getView` gets executed which fires your `OnCheckedChangeListener` method.

```
vhold.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
if(chonditionforchecking) {
    vhold.checkbox.setChecked(true);
} else { 
    vhold.checkbox.setChecked(false);
}
```

There are more solutions on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100518/checkbox-auto-call-oncheckedchange-when-listview-scroll)

Comment: Or, more precisely, `vhold.checkbox.setChecked(chonditionforchecking)`